# Create function to fit multiple models to 1 dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a GLM to a small dataset, consisting of 5 columns of variables y, x1, x2, x3, x4, and 24 rows of data.
This is not a problem in itself, but with these predictive variables there are 2^4 models possible. I am trying to write a function such that it will create a GLM for all different models, and return the coefficients along with the AIC value in 1 table. Can anyone help me out?

The dataset looks like this:

`i    y     x1  x2  x5  x7
1  29.5 5.0208 1.0 2.0  4
2  27.9 4.5429 1.0 1.0  3
3  25.9 4.5573 1.0 1.0  3
4  29.9 5.0597 1.0 1.0  3
5  29.9 3.8910 1.0 1.0  3
6  30.9 5.8980 1.0 1.0  3
7  28.9 5.6039 1.0 0.0  3
8  35.9 5.8282 1.0 2.0  3
9  31.5 5.3003 1.0 1.0  3
10 31.0 6.2712 1.0 1.0  2
11 30.9 5.9592 1.0 2.0  3
12 30.0 5.0500 1.0 0.0  2
13 36.9 8.2464 1.5 2.0  4
14 41.9 6.6969 1.5 1.5  3
15 40.5 7.7841 1.5 1.0  3
16 43.9 9.0384 1.0 1.5  3
17 37.5 5.9894 1.0 2.0  3
18 37.9 7.5422 1.5 1.0  3
19 44.5 8.7951 1.5 2.0  4
20 37.9 6.0831 1.5 1.0  3
21 38.9 8.3607 1.5 2.0  4
22 36.9 8.1400 1.0 2.0  3
23 45.8 9.1416 1.5 1.5  4
24 25.9 4.9176 1.0 1.0  4`

And the dput is:

```
structure(list(y = c(29.5, 27.9, 25.9, 29.9, 29.9, 30.9, 28.9, 
35.9, 31.5, 31, 30.9, 30, 36.9, 41.9, 40.5, 43.9, 37.5, 37.9, 
44.5, 37.9, 38.9, 36.9, 45.8, 25.9), x1 = c(5.0208, 4.5429, 4.5573, 
5.0597, 3.891, 5.898, 5.6039, 5.8282, 5.3003, 6.2712, 5.9592, 
5.05, 8.2464, 6.6969, 7.7841, 9.0384, 5.9894, 7.5422, 8.7951, 
6.0831, 8.3607, 8.14, 9.1416, 4.9176), x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 
1, 1.5, 1), x5 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1.5, 
1, 1.5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1.5, 1), x7 = c(4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4)), .Names = c("y", 
"x1", "x2", "x5", "x7"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: There are more than 2^4 models, if you allow for interaction terms. You should probably look at `MASS::stepAIC`. It sounds like you want to do model selection via AIC and that's what said function is for.

Comment: Thank you. Though I don't think the use of interaction terms is what I'm meant to do. It is about whether the beta's are zero or not.

Answer (score 0):

I used the glmulti package (link below) a few years ago to do something similar to this. I don't know if it will work for your problem though (you should post your data or a subset of your data so people can try things out).

https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i12/v34i12.pdf